# How to get Spinner with required text color of specific items (or just title)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want a black text color when a country is chosen. When it isn't = "Country" I want is in gray color.

How to do this? I use:

```
<style name="searchSpinnerStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/start_register_lists</item>
</style>
```

to style my spinner. How to change color when there is no choosen country?

[image: This is my spinner]

Comment: You will need to write code for that in your activity not in xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make such changes in Spinner adapter as follows:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final String[] array;

        public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              String[] array) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, array);
            this.array = array;
        }


        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_items, parent, false);
            }
            TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            label.setText(array[position]);

            label.setTextColor(position==0?Color.Grey:Color.Black);
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: works, but I got another problem. It seems that text size of choosen value is smaller then in the others spinners - which I don't changed. `holder.nameTextView.setTextSize(R.dimen.search_textSize);` makes it font color the same as background color... How it is possible?

Comment: please share your spinner_item xml?

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/search_textSize"
         />` in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Try this with out adding relative view as parent and make textview width matchparent

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/app_text_color"
    android:textSize="20sp" />